# Apollo landing abort times T1, T2, T3,

Tags: apollo-program, apollo-11

In the transcript ([1](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.landing.html) and [2](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.postland.html)) of Apollo 11 lunar landing we can see ground control and crew talking about "T1" moment and "T2" moment:

- 102:47:09 Duke: ...T1. Over. Eagle, you are **Stay for T1**.
- 102:47:12 Armstrong: Roger. Understand, **Stay for T1**.
- 102:47:15 Duke: Roger. And we see you venting the Ox(idizer).
- ...
- 102:51:45 Duke: Eagle, Houston. You are **Stay for T2**. Over.
- 102:51:50 Duke: Correction, you're...
- 102:51:52 Armstrong: Roger. **Stay for T2**. We thank you.
- 102:51:54 Duke: Roger, sir.

I find very difficult to find official documentation explaining this 2 moments, so I tried collecting & comparing all the descent checklists in [this page](https://jumpjack.github.io/Apollo11LEMdata/index-checklists.html), based on images found [here](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/a11-cmpsbindex.html):

"T1" is explicitly declared at page 10 of [Timeline Book](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/Apollo11-LM-TimelineBook-excerpts.pdf):

[image: T1]

It means that T1 = PDI+15min, and PDI is defined at page 8 as being 102:35:13:

[image: PDI]

Hence T1 = 102:50:13

Then things become tricky, because apparently T1 is also defined as TD+3 (top of page 10):

[image: TD+3]

But page top also says that page itself covers period from TD+3 to T2... but apparently T2 is not explicitly declared: we only have a "no-stay" checklist at PDI + 19:30:

[image: PDI+19:30]

PDI+19:30 means 102:35:13 + 00:19:30, hence 102:54:43 .

**Is there any confirmation that this is T2 time?** I read about that T2 is instead the first time CSM comes back over the LM after one orbit.... but then I found also this on page 11:

[image: 1st REV]

**Is this "first CSM revolution"?** It occurs at 104:42:05, i.e. around 2 hours after touchdown (102:47:11 planned, 102:45:40 actual), and some sources declare that T2 was planned 2 hours after touchdown... But probably this is instead T3?

Then what is this on page 11?

[image: PDI+23]

- PDI+13 = 102:35:13 + 00:13:00 = 102:48:13
- PDI+23 = 102:35:13 + 00:23:00 = 102:58:13

Aldrin [in 1969 debriefing said](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.postland.html) "the Tig for this T-2 abort, which is PDI plus 23", explaining why ground control asked him to input 10254 "rather than something else" (which he typed wrong, he typed erroneously PDI+12).

I ended up with this preliminary table (from timeline, flight plan and CMP solo checklist), but I am really confused...

[image: time table]

Comment: I thought this would be defined in the Mission Rules, but if it is, I can't find it.

Comment: I have this vague recollection that it had something to do with whether the abort would be accomplished with the descent engine vs. the ascent engine. But I have no references to back that up, so it's probably completely wrong.

Comment: The descent engine tanks are suppose to be depleted at landing